# How to append the text from source file into destination file before the EOF in a destination file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 files. File 1: source.sh File 2: destination.sh

I want to insert the contents of File 1 into File 2. But i don't want to insert the contents at the end of the file. The last line of File 2 is "}"

I want to insert the content of File 1 into File 2 before "}"

**My exact code:**

```
xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

 xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

 xxx_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
```

**My destination.sh**

```
{
    zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

    zzz_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

    ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"


    ccc_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

    rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

    rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

    rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

    rrr_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
    **}**
```

I need to insert source.sh into destination.sh before **}**

Since it is in production i don't want to hard code any number to define the EOF... Any help is appreciated

Below is the output of the EOF in the destination file

I ran the commmand

```
{ echo "---------"; nl "$filenamelocal" | tail -n 4 ; echo "---------"; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `}` character is the only character in the last line and this is the only line with only a single `}`, you could append File1 to File2 and afterwards move the `}` to the last line.

In terms of code this would look like this:

```
# append file1 to file2
cat File1 >> File2
# move the curly brace to the end of the file (change in place (-i flag))
# /^}$/ search for a line which starts with a } and ends afterwards
# d     delete the line
# ;     next command
# $a    append at the last line
# }     curly brace character
sed -i '/^}$/d;$a}' File2
```

Comment: I have attached the output of my EOF in the destination file. Will your above code will work for my destination file?
Second thing...I don't want to take risk by directly appending the contents in place of }.
Is there any way we can compare before appending }
Or this there any way to append in the middle

Comment: The `sed` command deletes lines with single `}` and nothing else in them and create a `}` at the end of the file - so in case of your example it should work.
You can certainly compare the files with the `diff` utility. If you don't want to change the file in place you could remove the `-i` flag from `sed` and have a look at the output if this is the change you want. Appending in the middle of a file is a different matter which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423572/append-a-file-in-the-middle-of-another-file-in-bash)

Comment: sed will delete only the } in last line right?

Comment: For inserting in the middle i gave command like 
awk 'FNR==3{system("cat "${filenamelocal}"")} 1' "${my_file5}" it did not work

Comment: sed will delete } only in the last line right>

Comment: the command I wrote for `sed` in the answer will delete _every_ single line containing nothing but the `}`

Comment: so if in my file i have 10 } it will delete all?

Comment: yes. But you would _see_ the result without changing the file if you would try the `sed` comand without the `-i` flag.

Comment: @noAnthon...But in my case...not } are deleting...only the last } moves to the end and contents are appended at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try also - given your shell provides "process substitution" -

```
tac file2 | sed 1r<(tac file1) | tac
```